# Find an application file containing code for popup window

Tags: 14.04, application-development, system, find, source-code

Ubuntu 14.04 When launching installed third-party app, it displays a popup window with notification message. I want to find an application file which contains code that show this popup window. Is there a tool that can help to determine this file? 
At the very least, how to find the file by scanning "/" root directory for particular text strings, contained in this popup window?

Comment: What is the application, Is it a notify- message or a regular pop up window? The text is not necessarily in a (readable) file.

Comment: You tagged your question `source-code` - do you actually have the source code of this application? Or are you trying to locate strings inside a binary executable? The answers will be different.

Comment: 3rd-party utility for Linux, show popup notification message (built-in into application), require click to close it.  No source code, as I said, I want to locate strings inside a binary executables.

Comment: Without mentioning the application, impossible to tell. There is no standard location.

Comment: I mean find place that contains code for that popup, I think the approach is same for any application .

Comment: Not the same.  It depends on application.  Some might use gtk dialogs,  others at dialogs.  It's  also not always possible  to find out,  since  it could  be a compiled  binary

Comment: The binary location is `/usr/bin`, how to find string in binary? Does it exist anything close to BinText for Windows?

Comment: You can try the `strings` command - see `man strings`

Comment: Yes, that is. I find it: `strings somebinaryfile | grep text-to-find`

Comment: @steeldriver think you could post that as answer ?

Comment: @Serg - OK done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find strings within a compiled binary application, you can use the `strings` command - from `man strings`

```
NAME
       strings - print the strings of printable characters in files.

DESCRIPTION
       For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character
       sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given with
       the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.
```

For example,

```
$ strings -d /usr/bin/gnome-calculator | grep 'Mode$'
ButtonMode
Basic Mode
Advanced Mode
Financial Mode
Programming Mode
Keyboard Mode
```

or

```
$ strings -df /usr/bin/gnome-* | grep 'Restart$'
/usr/bin/gnome-software: Restart
```

Comment: One note: when I need to find a the whole sentence, that contain spaces, I need put it into single quotes?

Comment: @minto the usual rules of `grep` would apply - quotes, escapes, whole-word matches (`-w`), whole-line matches (`-x`)